# setEmptyView() doesn't seem to work for (Sherlock)ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listview, actionbarsherlock, android-listfragment

I have a `ListFragment` and I want to set its empty view, so I use the following code:

```
View emptyView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.collection_empty_view, null);
detailFragment.getListView().setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

for the following xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/empty_collection" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add_legislation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addText"
        android:text="@string/action_add_text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But nothing shows up!

I tried `detailFragment.getListView().setEmptyText()`, and that *did* work! Am I doing domething wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The empty view has to be in the same view hierarchy as the list view.  Inflating it that way won't work.

Generally I create a layout in the format below:

```
<Layout>
    <ListView/>
    <View android:id="@+id/empty"/>
</Layout>
```

Where empty view is the View I want to use as my "empty view".  Then in on create I get a reference to the empty view and call setEmptyView() with that reference.

Here's an example from the Android documentation (check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html), it should be applicable to SherlockListFragment):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="8dp"
         android:paddingRight="8dp">

     <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#00FF00"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

     <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#FF0000"
               android:text="No data"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Works great! Only thing I'd like to add is that if you still want to use a `ListFragment`, the list id should be `android.R.id.list`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something which I'm doing in a fragment of my application.
I don't know if it's a good practice but it works!

```
View emptyView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.empty, null);
getActivity().setContentView(emptyView);
```