# Android: Change listview layout when searching adapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a listview with adapter, when searching the listview for **NON existing** item I want to display a layout for adding new one, I want to display it inside the listview to make it easy for the user and not moving to another window or popup dialog.

- When the user searches an existing item then I do a query (adapter) and display the appropriate results.
- And when the query doesn't find the item I should display the view for adding a new one inside the listview?

Ho can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add view having same width and height as that of Listview set visibility to INVISIBLE, in onCreate() load the data in listview check if data size greater than 0 (zero) then hide that view and if data size if its less than or equal to 0 (zero) show view. View should contain edittext and button to add new row in listview, once data is added hide the view again.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by checking the size of listview, if the size is 0 then in your adapter class set row count to one and add a custom view to get view method. from this view you can add data to list and make call to adapter.notifydatasetchange().

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go here

- Manually: if you have no results, then instead of updating your adapter, you set the list visibility to GONE and show your custom view to add a new one.
- Automatically: list view has a property called, emptyView if you set your "add" layout as this emptyView it will show up when your adapter is empty

Comment: How, I didn't success to do that, and I have searched the Internet and there were many explanations, but I didn't manage to make it run, any idea? شكرا الك

Comment: Which one exactly didn't succeed ?

Comment: check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472137/setemptyview-doesnt-seem-to-work-for-sherlocklistfragment